# Selenium: "handshake failed..."

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently working with Selenium to scrape homework website Slader. However, when I do so, I get an error.

```
[7072:2356:0304/142220.483:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

I've added:

```
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
```

But it still yields the same error. FYI, I'm using Chrome. It doesn't seem to interrupt the program but I'm curious why it's happening.

Comment: there could be a lot of reasons for that error... but check to see if you have Amazon's Root CA installed on that browser.  Also see: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/

Comment: Your chrome is probably out of date.

Comment: I've just updated ChromeDriver but now I get net_error 107. Still seems like an SSL issue though.